# Multiple developers commit on a feature branch

Tags: git, workflow, branching-and-merging

We've established inside the team that we will use feature branches for development.
One and only one developer handles a feature and is the owner of that branch at a given time.

The fuzzy/unclear part is that, after the review is performed by another developer and he ads annotations to the model ( UML schemas, not code ) it would be easy that he commits on top of the owner, on the same feature branch

Does this breaks any ethics/good practice of GIT ?

An alternative will be a review branch forked from the feature branch. But that will add complexity inside git branches.

What's more ethical and best practice, use commit review suggestions inside the UML schema on the same feature branch by the reviewer, or use separate review branch ?

Comment: _One and only one developer handles a feature and is the owner of that branch at a given time_. This just isn't how the real world works. The fact that you've run into this problem so quickly shows that.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, other developers are providing review comments and suggesting some changes. You should handle it in the same branch. Maintaining same branch for all changes including main changes and review comments (with combination of creating pull requests) will be efficient and more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to do reviews in an environment such as gitlab (merge request) or github (pull request) where you can easily write comments next to the lines changed. The ones responsible for the code can then change this according to how they want it.

If however others do commit and push on the feature branch maintain those changes in that branch if its relevant for the feature else cherry-pick them into a seperate branch (from master) starting a seperate review session.

Once every 'comment' is solved the feature branch may be merged or rebased on top of master.

Regarding the models/schemas mentioned. I don't think they should live within the code-repository but rather on some kind of wiki/docs page. These wiki pages mostly have a history in it aswell which can also be commented on.